# Use SMO to Change SQL Server Database Default Locations

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, smo

I am using the following code to change the server database default locations (where the SQL Server keeps new database files and log files):

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;

Server smoServer = new Server(new ServerConnection(server, username, password));
server.DefaultFile = newPath;
server.Alter();
server.Refresh();

// Now create a database in the new location
Database smoDatabase = new Database(smoServer, database);
smoDatabase.Create();
smoServer.Refresh();
```

Here's my problem:  I can look in SQL Server Management Studio and see the server property for Database Default Locations has been changed to the `newPath`.  However, when I use SMO to create a new database, the new database and logfile are created in the old path.

Once I restart the SQL Server instance, the SMO code creates the database/logfile in the new path.

Any ideas why I'm getting this behavior?

**Edit:** One suggestion is that the change doesn't actually take place until the Sql Server Instance is restarted.  However, if I open up SSMS and create a new database on the instance, it gets created in the new path *without having to restart*.

Comment: I've got the same problem and it's driving me nuts!

Answer (score 7):

You need to add information about Data and Log files explicitly:

```
// Now create a database in the new location
Database smoDatabase = new Database(smoServer, database);

FileGroup fg = new FileGroup(smoDatabase, "PRIMARY");
DataFile df = new DataFile(fg, "File1", @"c:\sql\file1.mdf");
LogFile lf = new LogFile(smoDatabase, "Log01", @"c:\sql\Log1.ldf");


smoDatabase.Create();
smoServer.Refresh();
```