# Programmatically modifying the file path location for a C# SMO created database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, smo

I am trying to programmatically create a new database using SMO in C#. For this project, I do not want the .mdf/.ldf files placed in the default folder 
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQL2008R2\MSSQL\DATA". I have not found anything on the web that tells how to modify the setting for the file location.

I get a failed operation exception when I run the following code:

```
Server srv = new Server(serverName.Text);

var db = new Database(srv, dbName.Text);            

db.Create();

DataFile df = new DataFile(db.FileGroups["PRIMARY"],
    dbName.Text, pathText.Text + dbName.Text + "_data.mdf");

df.Create();

LogFile lf = new LogFile(db, "Log01", pathText.Text + dbName.Text + "_log.ldf");
lf.Create();
```

The exception occurs at the `df.Create();` line.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think this one answers the question for you.
[Use SMO to Change SQL Server Database Default Locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331095/use-smo-to-change-sql-server-database-default-locations)

**TTRider's Answer was:**
You need to add information about Data and Log files explicitly:

Comment: Thanks. New code based on your suggestion: 
                Server srv = new Server(serverName.Text);
            
            srv.DefaultFile = pathText.Text;
            srv.Alter();
            srv.Refresh();
            Database smoDatabase = new Database(srv, dbName.Text);
            smoDatabase.Create();
            srv.Refresh();
The srv.DefaultFile made no difference. It did not crash this time but still ended up in the default location.

Answer (score 0):

TTRider's answer in the linked question points in the right direction, but is incomplete. Using some additional info from [this post](https://naturalselectiondba.wordpress.com/2015/06/10/standardising-new-database-creation-using-powershell-and-smo/) I was able to get it working (tested with SMO 2016 libraries).

```
private void CreateDatabase(string connectionString, string databaseName, string dataFilePath)
{
    using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        ServerConnection serverConnection = new ServerConnection(sqlConnection);
        Server sqlServer = new Server(serverConnection);
        Database smoDatabase = new Database(sqlServer, databaseName);

        string dataFileName = string.Format("{0}_Data", databaseName);
        string dataFileFullPath = Path.ChangeExtension(Path.Combine(dataFilePath, dataFileName), ".mdf");
        string logFileName = string.Format("{0}_Log", databaseName);
        string logFileFullPath = Path.ChangeExtension(Path.Combine(dataFilePath, logFileName), ".ldf");

        FileGroup fileGroup = new FileGroup(smoDatabase, "PRIMARY");
        smoDatabase.FileGroups.Add(fileGroup);

        DataFile dataFile = new DataFile(fileGroup, dataFileName, dataFileFullPath);
        dataFile.IsPrimaryFile = true;
        fileGroup.Files.Add(dataFile);

        LogFile logFile = new LogFile(smoDatabase, logFileName, logFileFullPath);
        smoDatabase.LogFiles.Add(logFile);

        smoDatabase.Create();

        serverConnection.Disconnect();
    }
}
```